# How to resolve the error InvalidOperationException in Microsoft Visual Studio 2019?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-identity

When I go to the controller it gives me this error

> "InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserManager`1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUser]' while attempting to activate 'AvaliacaoRestaurante.Controllers.FotoController'."

is the problem at startup do I have to add or remove something?

```
        services.AddDefaultIdentity<ApplicationUser>(options =>
            options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
                   .AddRoles<IdentityRole>() 
                   .AddEntityFrameworkStores<AvaliacaoRestaurantesDB>();
        services.AddControllersWithViews();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your above code in Startup.cs something like that.

```
    services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>(options =>
            {
               options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedEmail = true;
            })
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<AvaliacaoRestaurantesDB>();
           
            services.AddControllersWithViews();
```

And You must use the same class in your controller when injecting it:-

```
public FotoController(UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager)
```

because you used `ApplicationUser` in startup, not `IdentityUser` so this type is not registered with the injection system.I think it's will resolve your issue.

Comment: i did it and it's not working :( @Pritom Sarkar

Comment: @GuyPeace makesure inherit your ApplicationUser with  IdentityUser like  ```public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser```

Answer (score 0):

Did you register identity in your `ConfigureServices` method (class Startup)? You have to find a line like the following:

`services.AddIdentity<UserIdentity, RoleIdentity>(...)`